# Roulette simulator with two Green slots, but want to bet only in Red/Green

Tags: python-2.7

How would you create a script to determine winning chance of a gambler who bet only on Black/Red slots out of 18 Blacks, 18 Reds, and 2 Greens?

Currently I am stuck with the 50/50 script (Python-2.7) and have absolutely no idea how to add the 5.26% chance of the greens.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

```
def betting(money, loop_num):
    guess = randint(0,1)
    result = randint(0,1)
    if guess == result:
        money += bet*70
        main(money, loop_num)
    else:
        money -= bet
        main(money, loop_num)
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: Thank you, I've added in the codes now. Used to have random.choice to but it is pointless so it was edited out.

Comment: Dont use a random integer between 0 and 1. Use a random float between 0 and 1. If the result is lower than the probability of one guess (if randfloat <= 0.4737 -> good guess, else fail)

Comment: Thank you very much derM for your kind advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
def betting(money, loop_num):
    result = random()
    if result <= 0.4737 : // given your 5.26% are right
        money += bet*70
        main(money, loop_num -1)
    else:
        money -= bet
        main(money, loop_num - 1)
```

No matter which one he *guesses* - the probability won't change.
Do not forgett to decrese the loop_num, to break the recursion.

Comment: Wow, never thought of this method. Thank you very much.